# Pyspark: how to read files from GS bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I am trying to read .csv file from pyspark.

I did set up a virtual machine in one project and the bucket in another one.

This is what I am doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/lib/spark/')
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as fs
from google.cloud import storage
from pyspark import SparkContext
import os
path = 'myBucket-c892b51f8579.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = path
client = storage.Client()
name = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/myBucket/'
bucket_id = 'myBucket'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_id)


sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
#spark.conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop2-2.1.2')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.impl', 'com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem') 
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable', 'true')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile', "myBucket-c892b51f8579.json")
# Following are required if you are using oAuth
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.client.id', '1166340800441514xxxxx')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.client.secret', 'c892b51f85798cb8dcc57d0011fa76beabaxxxxx')
```

I can read the file as a pandas dataframe but not with pyspark.

```
for i, file in enumerate(client.list_blobs(bucket_id, prefix='myFolder')):
    file_path="gs://{}/{}".format(file.bucket.name, file.name)
    if i == 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path) 
        print("Print Datataframe from pandas\n")  #### PRINT DATAFRAME
        print(df.head(5))
        df1  = spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").load([file_path])
```

This is the output

```
Print Datataframe from pandas
                             identifier identifier_type                timestamp       time_zone_name  ...  province_short        ip_address device_horizontal_accuracy                                          source_id
0  ea48f283-494f-4e84-8369-94c0340b749e            idfa  2020-03-18 23:59:16 UTC      America/Chicago  ...           US.TX     99.43.106.241                  18.000000  6d7f114f73b49b40aa15260a856b51068b9181ea628f71...
1  9b91c8a3-468f-457c-9837-af6118a8f034            idfa  2020-03-18 05:58:20 UTC      America/Chicago  ...           US.TX     73.232.180.67                   7.000000  2051ff772f65f048db9f2f32c2d02b548599f2a3e4254c...
2  58bddd43-7cdd-4cf5-9de7-bee91a04153c            idfa  2020-03-19 05:00:01 UTC  America/Los_Angeles  ...           US.CA      71.95.63.254                  10.000000  6d7f114f73b49b40aa15260a856b51068b9181ea628f71...
3  985fbdb5-86fe-4ede-9ef9-aeeda57b06a3            idfa  2020-03-18 13:51:40 UTC      America/Chicago  ...           US.TX  2600:387:a:9::78                1627.838517  cda89525af15a7e5ede988453fe40b348163bdf56fcd66...
4  c2be7747-2bb2-4d4c-9110-442d3837b99c            gaid  2020-03-18 07:53:08 UTC  America/Los_Angeles  ...           US.CA      172.58.39.47                   8.000000  9e6c1827914b40ea5d2a437ebc4a9cd6ef486b4688a304...

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.load.
: java.io.IOException: Error accessing Bucket myVirtualMachine-staging-us-central1-939717789215-lkntecyc

Caused by: com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "myName@myBucket.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to myVirtualMachine-staging-us-central1-939717789215-lkntecyc.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "emanmyNameuele@myBucketiam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to myVirtualMachine-staging-us-central1-939717789215-lkntecyc."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP code 403 represents client is forbidden from accessing the URL. Clearly a permissions issue.

Service account does not have `storage.buckets.get` permission on myVirtualMachine-staging-us-central1-939717789215-lkntecyc bucket.

You can get permissions for all service accounts using following command:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy
```

If you have sufficient permissions, you can assign `roles/storage.objectViewer` role for this specific bucket to this service account using following [gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#gsutil).

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:my-service-account@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.objectViewer gs://my-project/my-bucket
```

Comment: If the permissions are not the problem, do you know how to solve the problem? I also can read my dataframe with pandas but not with pyspark